# how can I start small embedded programming/project in PC?

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, kernel, device-driver

My friend very much interested in Embedded system. He wants to learn embedded system by doing or starting with some small small embedded projects or programs. Like switching between processes/tasks, interrupt generation, device driver programming (where he can learn proper usage of volatile, const etc), linux system level programming and all. Please suggest me some good websites where he can start learning creating small small programs or projects in embedded system.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Traditional embedded systems are not related to PC or Linux at all. If you really want to learn about embedded systems you should get yourself a kit with a microcontroller on a PCB, then make a "raw" program for it without any OS.

Comment: @Lundin: Could you please provide me some website references where he can buy some kits.

Comment: My personal favourite for various hobbyist projects would be the [Freescale HCS08 8-bit MCU](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=S08QD&nodeId=01624684491437&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab). This one, S08QD, is the simplest MCU in that family and it doesn't come with a lot of on-chip peripherals. Depending on what project you want to do, it may or may not be suitable. The Freescale Codewarrior C compiler is free to use and download.

Comment: Funnily enough, the "small small embedded projects" like -list, is a list of some of the biggest and hairiest things you find in embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [**osdev.org**](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) (it is a wiki-based website about developing OSes).

It is a good starting point for learning operating system architecture in general and particularly OSes for emebedded devices.

Also a good option is to join some existing opensource project to "touch it" by hands. Some examples:

- [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) - educational OS created by Andrew S. Tanenbaum.
- [Linux](http://www.kernel.org/) and [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/) kernels - if your friend already has some experience.

Or consider less known homegrown kernels, that are likely much easier to enter. Personally, I'm developing [Embox](http://code.google.com/p/embox/) embedded operating system kernel.

Good luck!

Comment: The above link is just a website for learning OS or "OSDEV" is the name of an OS (Like Linux, Unix, freeRTOS and all)?

Comment: And my friend is looking for some code related websites.

Comment: How could he start device driver programming?

Answer (score 2):

One option that comes to mind is [Xinu](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dec/xsoft.html) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinu)

Another is [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)

[Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) is a popular hardware option